# How can I generate a Tailwind Grid that uses dynamic height?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Is it possible to generate a grid where the column items adapt to the content and remain in a mosaic layout with Tailwind CSS?

For example, if I add divs or collapse items, the size should grow and the same in reverse.

Actual:
[image]

Expected:
[image]

**Code:**

```
<div class="p-10 bg-slate-200">
<div class="mt-10 grid grid-cols-2 justify-center gap-4 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-2">
  <div class="bg-red-400">
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-red-200">02</div>
  <div class="bg-red-200">03</div>
  <div class="bg-red-400">
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried span? look at the docs here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-row

Comment: @SalmanMalik, yes but no works like i expected. If a column is bigger, the one next to it has that size

Comment: Here you go, you can create rows and make it flow to cols and then simply span the rows to replicate what you desire here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/wNYs81xFmL